# MySQL 'JOIN' fetches data from only one table when used along with 'LIMIT'

Tags: mysql

**Solved**

I was using DB class to bind values in a string using `query` method. Which roughly looks like this:

```
public function query($sql,$params = array()) {
    ...
    $x = 0;
    foreach($params as $param) {
        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param)
        $x++;
    }
    ...
    //Fetch Results....
}
```

First I was using this string to pass to `query` method;

```
SELECT * FROM user_info u JOIN users us ON u.user_id = us.user_id 
WHERE u.branch IN (?) AND us.status IN (?) AND us.email_activation IN (?) 
ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?,?
```

Then I switched to the following string

```
SELECT * FROM user_info u JOIN users us ON u.user_id = us.user_id 
WHERE u.branch IN (?) AND us.status IN (?) AND us.email_activation IN (?) 
ORDER BY u.user_id ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

Then it somehow worked. Probably it (the `query` method) was trying to bind value as a string or another type which is not suitable for the `LIMIT` clause.

---

Question

I'm trying to implement a search function in which users can use bunch of filters to narrow down the results. I have 2 different tables (users, user_info) in my database. They have one column in common which is named 'user_id'.
In `users` table users' status is stored (e.g. email is validated or not, registration is accepted by the admin or not etc.) In `user_info` table, users' personal iformations are stored.

**user_info table**

[image: user_info table]

**users table**

[image: users table]

To cut the story short I collect applied filters and create a query string like below:

```
SELECT u.*, us.* 
FROM user_info u 
LEFT JOIN users us ON u.user_id = us.user_id 
WHERE u.branch IN (?) AND  u.state IN (?) AND  u.city IN (?) 
AND us.status IN (?) AND us.email_activation IN (?) 
ORDER BY ? ?
LIMIT ?,?
```

Using the above query results in only the rows that in `users` and satisfying the conditions for the `users` columns(email_activation and status) are being returned. No matter what condition I specify for the 'user_info' columns.

But if I rearrange the string like the one below (deleting `LIMIT`), I get what I want. Both tables' conditions are satisfied.

```
SELECT u.*, us.* 
FROM user_info u 
LEFT JOIN users us ON u.user_id = us.user_id 
WHERE u.branch IN (?) AND  u.state IN (?) AND  u.city IN (?) 
AND us.status IN (?) AND us.email_activation IN (?) 
ORDER BY ? ?
```

**Results,**

```
        **Without LIMIT**
        [id] => 15
        [user_id] => 11
        [branch] => 4
        [date_of_birth] => ..
        [location] => ..
        [city] => ..
        [state] =>  ..
        [weight] => ..
        [height] => ..
        [bio] => ..
        ...
        [name] => ..
        [lastname] => .. 
        [mail] => ..
        [password] => .. 
        [salt] => ..
        [joined] => ..
        [authority] => ..
        [status] => 1
        [email_activation] => 1

        **With LIMIT (no column from the user_info table)**
        [user_id] => 11
        [name] => 
        [lastname] => 
        [mail] =>
        [password] => 
        [salt] => 
        [joined] => 
        [authority] => 1
        [status] => 1
        [activation_code] => 
        [email_activation] => 1
```

**EDIT:** 
Without limiting the results, I normally get 2 rows. 
For the values of `LIMIT` clause I use:
OFFSET 0, LIMIT 1 ---> LIMIT 0,1

Table samples and result samples are added

DB Class uses this line of code to bind values
    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);

The query with the real values looks like this

```
SELECT u.*, us.* 
FROM user_info u 
LEFT JOIN users us ON u.user_id = us.user_id 
WHERE u.branch IN (4) AND  u.state IN (1) AND  u.city IN (1) 
AND us.status IN (1) AND us.email_activation IN (1) 
ORDER BY user_id ASC
```

Comment: how much is the limit .. ?   could be that your result with ordered result is minus that the limit for see other result ..  ... limit define only the number of the rows you return in select  no effect on filter ..

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @scaisEdge If I omit the `LIMIT` I get 2 results. Therefore I use LIMIT 1,0

Comment: update your question adding a proper data sample the result and the expected  result ..

Comment: What are you _actually_ passing in place of the `?` placeholders? Are those just there for query sample purposes, or are you attempting to put in a delimited string inside _one_ `?` placeholder within `IN ()`? That won't produce expected results in many database APIs because the whole delimited string is treated as a _single_ value.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I don't use delimited string. A `?` respresents one value. If I want to use more than one value inside the `IN`, I add more `?` Actually I'm just using **integer**s. The query passed to DB class in which I use `bindValue`. I will edit the question to add the `code line` that the DB class use and the _final_ query string (?'s are replaced with the real values)

Comment: I can't think of any way use of `LIMIT` could affect the *columns* returned by a query. I have to assume some detail about your real case has been lost as you translated it to this question.

Comment: It could also be that you have two instances of your application in your test environment, with different SQL code, and you got confused about which one you were testing. I've done that, and I've seen lots of people asking questions on SO figure out that they were doing that too.

Answer (score 0):

You got it the other way around. OFFSET 0, LIMIT 1 ---> LIMIT 0,1

Comment: Apparently I made a typo in the original question. I was using the way you recommended.

Comment: @Zeki I don't see 'city' or 'state' in the results of the query without LIMIT.

Comment: I chopped off some elements of the resulting array to shorten the question. I should correct that.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you take off 'LEFT' from the JOIN?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. But now I am close to the solution. In a seperate php file ``test.php` I tried couple queries and tried to get a result. By using the following query I was able to achieve what I wish for. ` "SELECT * FROM user_info u JOIN users us ON u.user_id = us.user_id WHERE u.branch IN (?) AND us.status IN (?) AND us.email_activation IN (?) ORDER BY u.user_id DESC LIMIT 1";` (I replaced placeholders with the actual values)